# call controller method and return variable to view

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I call a method about a form?

I have 3 `radio` buttons and I want to call a method depending on which radio button is checked. After the call I have to return the controller a variable to the view.

How can I do that?

My approach:

I want use CSS do design my HTML. That is the reason why I haven't used a form helper:

```
<div id="cx" class="cxs">
  <form>
    <fieldset>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" id="cxId" name="checkBox"> ID
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" id="cxName" name="checkBox"> Name
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" id="cxArtikelnummer" name="checkBox"> Artikelnummer
      </label>
    </fieldset>
    <button type="button" id="cxBtn">Ok</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Here I want to call a method depending on which radio button is checked (show by `name`, `id` or `artikelnummer`).

I have solved it stati, but the choose have to be dynamic and I thought do that with methods.

```
<% $i = 0 %>
  <% $num = @title.count %>
  <% @title.each do |row| %>
    Name: <%= row["Name"] %>
    Durchlauf: <%= $i %> <br>
  <% $i += 1 %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: what is `@title`? where is it initialised?

Comment: sorry, title is initialised in my controller. "@title = data_array" title is an 2d array

Comment: you can set `name` as your `method_name`, and when selected you can call the corresponding method using `send(method_name.to_sym)`.

Comment: i dont understand it. can you give me an example?

Comment: _"Here I want to call a method depending on which radio button is checked"_ did you consider to use JS to do what you want?

Comment: retype your question please @Kev_Kev, code with code and text with text.

Answer (score 2):

If @title represents a model in which there is for example "aaa" field of string type which can have the "ID" value, "Name" value and "Artikelnummer", try use this:

```
<% @title.each do |row| %>
      <% if row.aaa == "ID" %>
          #code for ID option
      <% elsif row.aaa == "Name" %>
          #code for Name option
      <% elsif row.aaa == "Artikelnummer %>
          #code for Artikelnummer option
      <% end %>
<% end %>
```

That is my idea. Tell me if it will help you.

But I think you can use form_for helper and radio_button helper inside with its :checked option and the whole form_for you can design via CSS via classes for every `<li class="sth"><%= f.radio_button "Name", checked: true%></li>` but I should check if this solution is right.

Rgds, 
Marta

Comment: Bad thing is he's trying to do something when the radio button is checked. So isn't completelly a server side issue.